# VBA - Find all matches across multiple sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a macro that will search an entire workbook for various codes. These codes are all six digit numbers. Codes I wish to search for are input in column A of a sheet called "Master". If a code found on another sheet matches one in Master it's sheet name and cell will be pasted in column B next to it's match in Master. When successful the end result looks like this.

[image]

The code posted below  works in certain cases, but fails quite often. Occasionally a run-time error will appear, or an error message with "400" and nothing else. When these errors occur the macro fills a row with matches for a blank value at the end of all the listed codes. This is obviously not an intended function.

[image]

I am at a loss regarding the above error. I have wondered if limiting the search range would help stability. All codes on other sheets are only found in column A, so searching for matches in all columns as is done currently is quite wasteful. Speed is secondary to stability however, I first want to eliminate all points of failure.

```
Sub MasterFill()

Dim rngCell As Range
Dim rngCellLoc As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lngLstRow As Long
Dim lngLstCol As Long
Dim strSearch As String

Sheets("Master").Select
lngLstRowLoc = Sheets("Master").UsedRange.Rows.Count
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each rngCellLoc In Range("A1:A" & lngLstRowLoc)
    i = 1
        For Each ws In Worksheets
            If ws.Name = "Master" Then GoTo SkipMe
                lngLstRow = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
                lngLstCol = ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count
                ws.Select
                    For Each rngCell In Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(lngLstRow, lngLstCol))
                        If InStr(rngCell.Value, rngCellLoc) > 0 Then
                            If rngCellLoc.Offset(0, i).Value = "" Then
                                rngCellLoc.Offset(0, i).Value = ws.Name & " " & rngCell.Address
                                i = i + 1
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next
SkipMe:
        Next ws
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Worksheets("Master").Activate
    MsgBox "All done!"
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to use InStr as your criteria logic? **123** will be found within **012345**. Beyond that, a cell by cell search is a lot slower than .Find/.FindNext.

Comment: Also, a note, instead of using a [`GoTo`](https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/goto.png), just do `If ws.Name <> "Master" Then ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if this doesn't expedite matters while correcting the logic.

```
Sub MasterFill()
    Dim addr As String, fndCell As Range
    Dim rngCellLoc As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Worksheets("Master")
        For Each rngCellLoc In .Range(.Cells(1, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
            For Each ws In Worksheets
                If LCase(ws.Name) <> "master" Then
                    With ws.Columns("A")
                        Set fndCell = .Find(what:=rngCellLoc.Value2, After:=.Cells(1), _
                                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, _
                                            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
                        If Not fndCell Is Nothing Then
                            addr = fndCell.Address(0, 0)
                            Do
                                With rngCellLoc
                                    .Cells(1, .Parent.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1) = _
                                        Join(Array(ws.Name, fndCell.Address(0, 0)), Chr(32))
                                End With
                                Set fndCell = .FindNext(After:=fndCell)
                            Loop While addr <> fndCell.Address(0, 0)
                        End If
                    End With
                End If
            Next ws
        Next
        .Activate
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "All done!"
End Sub
```

1. I've used LookAt:=xlPart in keeping with your use of InStr for criteria logic; if you are only interested in whole cell values change this to LookAt:=xlWhole.
2. I've restricted the search range to column A in each worksheet.
3. Previous results are not cleared before adding new results.
4. Your own error was due to the behavior where a zero length string (blank or vbNullString) is found within any other string when determined by Instr.

Comment: This is incredible, thank you so much! It finishes near instantly and succeeds in every worksheet I have tested so far. Your ending comments are quite informative as well.